# Get the time when session starts with Pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher

Is there a way to get time when a session starts using Pusher? 
  I have a working environment in which I can broadcast data. I am looking for a way to get the time when the session starts and finishes. Is Pusher good for 
 it?

Comment: Pusher is for broadcasting and has nothing to do with sessions, do you want to mark the time a browser subscribed to Pusher instead? like when a user connected to the chat?

Comment: @Caddy DZ  Yes, this is what I mean. I have to store the time when the user connects and disconnects. Can I do this with Pusher?